# Access 36-bit physical address from 32-bit userspace

Tags: linux, memory, memory-mapping

I am working on a system in which the memory mapping is done using 36-bit addressing. In particular I am trying to access the PCIe memory space (that is mapped to `0xc00000000` address) from a 32-bit userspace Linux application.

I had plan to use `mmap` for this purpose but the last argument of `mmap` is of type `off_t` which is 4-bytes wide on a 32-bit OS. Can someone guide how to access the address `0xc00000000` from userspace app using `mmap`?

P.S: My machine is running 32-bit versions of both Linux Kernel and RootFS.

Comment: What is the linux kernel version? What do you mean by "32-bit version of ... Filesystem"? (does filesystems has bit width versions?) Can you go the way of modifying your kernel or you want not to make any changes in the kernel and find some way of doing that from userspace only?

Comment: Kernel version is 4.1.35. I guess the filesystem having 32-bit applications is referred to as 32-bit filesystem. I was preferring doing that from userspace but kernel modification can also be an option if you suggest.

Comment: The filesystem does not care what "bit width" application have, it just stores bits whatever and however it wants. The kernel that is responsible for running the program must "undestand" the program - so the architecture of the program need to be compatible with what kernel understands. How the program is stored in whatever medium there is, has nothing to do with it. Anyway, a simple solution would be to recompile the kernel with `off_t` to be 64-bit (google said me you need `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`)

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I was talking about rootfs rather then filesystem. Ok I will check that option and update here.